# Gradle name-bound task types

Tags: java, gradle

When creating a task with the name `jar`, Gradle automatically knows that the class of the task is `org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar`. How can I replicate this with my custom task?

i.e. I have the following class:

```
class MyTaskType extends DefaultTask {
    @Input String name

    // Options

    @TaskAction
    def generateImage() {
        // Stuff
    }
}
```

Up until now I've been doing the following:

```
task veryCoolTaskName(type:MyTaskType) {
    name 'some-name'
}
```

And I want to be able to define a task of this type by writing:

```
myTaskType {
    name 'some-name'
}
```

Just like with `jar {...}`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is not how Gradle works.**

When writing `jar { ... }`, you don't actually create a new task. Instead, you are refererring to an existing task `jar` that was created by a plugin (e.g. the [Java plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html)):

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

jar {
    // This works because the task was created by the plugin
}
```

Without any plugin applied, the same excerpt will fail, as a task named `jar` does not exist:

```
jar {
    // This fails, because the task `jar` does not exist
}
```

Instead, you need to create the task to configure it:

```
task jar(type: Jar)

jar {
    // This works because the task was created beforehand
}
```

Of course, the creation and the configuration of the task may be combined:

```
task jar(type: Jar) {
    // ... 
}
```